# intepretation of Valgrind output to figure out the location of data race

Tags: c++, multithreading, valgrind

The following is an output from running Helgrind,which detects data races. It suggests
that memory location 0x5C8AD88 was shared without being protected.

```
==7568== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==7568== 
==7568== Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0x5C8AD88 by thread #3
==7568== Locks held: none
==7568==    at 0x406616: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::_S_right(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (stl_tree.h:535)
==7568==    by 0x4102F1: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::equal_range(long const&) (stl_tree.h:1174)
==7568==    by 0x40FE1E: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::erase(long const&) (stl_tree.h:1521)
==7568==    by 0x40FA70: std::map<long, demon::Edge*, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::erase(long const&) (stl_map.h:654)
==7568==    by 0x40F599: demon::Vertex::eliminate(demon::CGraph&) (Vertex.cpp:286)
==7568==    by 0x404723: demon::CGraph::reverse_eliminate(int, demon::CGPart*) (CGraph.cpp:390)
==7568==    by 0x404959: demon::CGraph::reverse_eliminate(void*) (CGraph.cpp:441)
==7568==    by 0x40CC74: ThreadPool::execute_task(void*) (ThreadPool.cpp:156)
==7568==    by 0x4C2ED9D: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7568==    by 0x4E3DE0E: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==7568==    by 0x59547DC: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==7568== 
==7568== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #1
==7568== Locks held: none
==7568==    at 0x50CB6B0: std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==7568==    by 0x410165: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&) (stl_tree.h:981)
==7568==    by 0x40FD6D: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::_M_insert_unique(std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&) (stl_tree.h:1299)
==7568==    by 0x40FA28: std::map<long, demon::Edge*, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::insert(std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&) (stl_map.h:523)
==7568==    by 0x40EFF4: demon::Vertex::add_in_edge(demon::Vertex*, double) (Vertex.cpp:213)
==7568==    by 0x4049AA: demon::CGraph::add_edge(demon::Vertex*, demon::Vertex*, double) (CGraph.cpp:453)
==7568==    by 0x408AB4: demon::CGBuilder::build_cg(demon::active const&, double, demon::active const&, double, demon::active const&, bool, bool) (CGBuilder.cpp:221)
==7568==    by 0x40314D: demon::binary_op(demon::active const&, double, demon::active const&, double, demon::active const&, bool, bool) (API.cpp:55)
==7568== 
==7568== Address 0x5C8AD88 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 48 alloc'd
==7568==    at 0x4C2BD37: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7568==    by 0x4108BE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:94)
==7568==    by 0x410795: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::_M_get_node() (stl_tree.h:369)
==7568==    by 0x410516: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::_M_create_node(std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&) (stl_tree.h:379)
==7568==    by 0x410146: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&) (stl_tree.h:979)
==7568==    by 0x40FD6D: std::_Rb_tree<long, std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> >, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::_M_insert_unique(std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&) (stl_tree.h:1299)
==7568==    by 0x40FA28: std::map<long, demon::Edge*, std::less<long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> > >::insert(std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&) (stl_map.h:523)
==7568==    by 0x40EFF4: demon::Vertex::add_in_edge(demon::Vertex*, double) (Vertex.cpp:213)
==7568==    by 0x4049AA: demon::CGraph::add_edge(demon::Vertex*, demon::Vertex*, double) (CGraph.cpp:453)
==7568==    by 0x40890F: demon::CGBuilder::build_cg(demon::active const&, double, demon::active const&, bool, bool, bool) (CGBuilder.cpp:170)
==7568==    by 0x4030D4: demon::unary_op(demon::active const&, double, demon::active const&, bool, bool, bool) (API.cpp:50)
==7568==    by 0x402629: demon::operator*(double, demon::active const&) (Active.cpp:92)
==7568== 
==7568== ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This function is exectued by Thread #1.

```
Edge * Vertex::add_in_edge( Vertex * src , double eval  )
{
        assert(src!=NULL);

    Edge *  in_et = new Edge( src, this, eval );

    in_edges.insert( std::pair<idx_t,Edge*>( src->idx , in_et ) );

    src->out_edges.insert( std::pair<idx_t,Edge*>( this->idx , in_et ) );

    //pthread_mutex_lock(&ostream_lock);

    //std::cout << "inside add_in_edge()" << std::endl;

    //std::cout << "address of new inedge " << in_et << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "address of this vertex " << this << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "address of this vertex idx " << &(this->idx) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "address of src vertex " << src << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "address of src vertex's outedge container " << &(src->out_edges) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "address of src vertex's inedge container " << &(src->in_edges) << std::endl;

    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&ostream_lock);

    return in_et;
}
```

This function is executed by Thread #3.

```
dim_t Vertex::eliminate( CGraph & cg )
{
        dim_t nMults = 0;

    std::map<idx_t,Edge*>::iterator inedge_it;

    std::map<idx_t,Edge*>::iterator outedge_it;

    dim_t m =  in_edges.size();
    dim_t n  = out_edges.size();

    //std::cout << "vertex " << idx << " is in block " << prt_idx << std::endl;

    for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )

        outedge_it->second->tgt->in_edges.erase(this->idx);

    for( inedge_it=in_edges.begin() ; inedge_it!=in_edges.end() ; inedge_it++ )
    {
        inedge_it->second->src->out_edges.erase(this->idx);

        //pthread_mutex_lock(&ostream_lock);

        //std::cout << "inside eliminate()" << std::endl;

        //std::cout << "address of this edge " << inedge_it->second << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "address of this vertex " << this << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "address of this vertex idx " << &(this->idx) << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "address of src vertex " << inedge_it->second->src << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "address of src vertex's inedge container " << &(inedge_it->second->src->in_edges) << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "address of src vertex's outedge container  " << &(inedge_it->second->src->out_edges) << std::endl;

        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&ostream_lock);

        for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )
        {   
            double cij = (inedge_it->second->eval)*(outedge_it->second->eval);

            nMults++;

            Edge * direct_link = NULL;

            std::map<idx_t,Edge*>::iterator direct_link_it;

            direct_link_it = inedge_it->second->src->out_edges.find(outedge_it->second->tgt->idx);

            if(direct_link_it!=inedge_it->second->src->out_edges.end())
            {
                direct_link = direct_link_it->second;
            }

            if(direct_link)
            {
                direct_link->eval += cij;

            }else
            {
                outedge_it->second->tgt->add_in_edge( inedge_it->second->src , cij );
            }
        }

        delete inedge_it->second;
    }

    for( outedge_it=out_edges.begin() ; outedge_it!=out_edges.end() ; outedge_it++ )
    {   
        delete outedge_it->second;
    }

    in_edges.clear();
    out_edges.clear();

    return nMults;
}
```

Here is how the class Vertex looks like. It has out_edges and in_edges to
store the outgoing and incoming edges, respectively.

```
class Vertex 
{
public :

    //unsigned char properties;

    bool live;

    bool temporary;

    bool local;

    /**************************************
    *the unique identifier for each vertex
    **************************************/
    idx_t idx;

    /********************************************
    *which block/partition the vertex belongs to    
    *********************************************/
    idx_t prt_idx;

    /*******************************************************
    *which kind of vertex the vertex is : INDEP,INTMED,DEP
    *******************************************************/
    vertex_t kind;

    /****************************************************************
    *maps src vertex indinces to the corresponding incoming edges
    *****************************************************************/

    std::map<idx_t,Edge*> in_edges;

    /*******************************************************************
    *maps target vertex indinces to the corresponding outgoing edges
    ********************************************************************/

    std::map<idx_t,Edge*> out_edges;

    static pthread_mutex_t ostream_lock;

};//end of class
```

I am trying to interpret the output and to figure out what variable is at location 0x5C8AD88.
Does the output suggest that the variable ***out_edges*** in inedge_it->second->src->out_edges (from function eliminate()) and src->out_edges.insert( std::pair( this->idx , in_et ) )( from add_in_edge ) is the culprit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the third block of output:

```
Address 0x5C8AD88 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 48 alloc'd
...
[...]::insert(std::pair<long const, demon::Edge*> const&)
demon::Vertex::add_in_edge(demon::Vertex*, double) (Vertex.cpp:213)
```

The data in question was created by `add_in_edge()` during an `insert()`.  You can really stop here.  The data race is somewhere your map structure.  And sure enough, your code does not show any locking around accesses to the maps.  You'll need to figure out a locking scheme for ALL accesses to both in_edges and out_edges.

When investigating locks, consider switching to `std::thread` from low-level pthreads.  If you're not using C++11, use `boost::thread` instead.  The mutex classes in those libraries are easier to use and less error-prone.

Comment: I tried printing out all the addresses as I did in the code( commented out) but I couldn't find the location 0x5C8AD88 printed out...

Comment: It's internal to either `in_edges` or `out_edges` as I mention above.  You won't find it directly.  All you need to know is that `map::insert()` allocated the memory that's triggering the problem.  It means you need to protect `insert`, along with all the other accesses to your maps.